# Understanding container_of

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to understand the container_of macro by writing a small program, but I'm not getting the expected results. The program I wrote is:

```
typedef struct node {
    int id1;
    int id2;
    struct node *next;
}node;

int main()
{
    node *n1, *n2;
    n1 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    n2 = malloc(sizeof(node));

    n1->id1 = 101;
    n1->id2 = 102;
    n1->next = n2;

    n2->id1 = 201;
    n2->id2 = 202;
    n2->next = NULL;

    node *obj = (node*)container_of(&n2, node, next);

    printf("%d\n", obj->id1);
    free(n1);
    free(n2);

    return 0;
 }
```

But with that code, I'm getting some random number as my answer. Any ideas where I could be wrong?

Comment: Where is `container_of` defined? There's no such macro in standard C.

Comment: @KeithThompson, see http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html. It's a very common macro.

Comment: @Kay: Looks like it's specific to the Linux kernel (which would be worth mentioning in the question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`container_of` is a popular utility macro, but nevertheless it is not a standard feature of the language.

The first parameter of `container_of` is supposed to point directly to a struct field, i.e. it is supposed to point directly to *a nested subobject of a bigger object*. That bigger object is the "container" that the name of the macro refers to.

Your are passing `&n2` - a pointer to a completely independent local variable. This is why it does not work. `n2` is an independent variable. It is not a part of any container.

An example of correct usage of `container_of` would be

```
node **pnext = &n2->next;
int *pid = &n1->id1;

...
// Assume that now we want to restore `n2` knowing only `pnext`
node *obj = container_of(pnext, node, next);
assert(obj == n2);

...
// Assume that now we want to restore `n1` knowing only `pid`
obj = container_of(pid, node, id1);
assert(obj == n1);
```

I.e. from a pointer to a *field* of `*n2` object you get a pointer to the *entire* `*n2` object itself. And from a pointer to a field of `*n1` object you get a pointer to the *entire* `*n1` object itself.

Why you are attempting to cast the result of `container_of` is not clear to me either. A traditional implementation of `container_of` already returns a properly converted pointer.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what `container_of` does. Is there any way for me to get `obj->id1` to return `101` when I give `container_of` a parameter of `n2`? Basically what I'm asking is, can I get `n1` from `n2` because `n1` "contains" `n2`?

Comment: @user3666471: No, it is not possible to get from `n2` to `n1`. `*n1` does not really "contain" `*n2` in `container_of` sense of the term. `*n1` simply refers to `*n2`. `*n1` contains `id1`, `id2` and pointer `next`. It contains the pointer itself, but it does not contain the referee of that pointer.

Comment: Follow up question, can `container_of` only work on pointers like the `next` member I have in my program? Say I pass `n1->id1` to a function, can I restore `n1` with only that data?

Comment: @user3666471: It can work with any field. But you have to have a *pointer* to that field. You need a *pointer* to `n1->id1` to restore `n1`, i.e. you need direct access to `n1->id1` as an lvalue. If all you have is a copy of data from `n1->id1`, then you cannot restore `n1`.